# Совершенный и несовершенный вид глаголов

Tags: глаголы

Спасибо за ответы, но  немного запутался.

Вопрос, заданный мне изначально, звучал так: "Я ходил вчера в кино". НСВ. Почему нельзя сказать: "Я ездил на год в город Х и поступил на курсы, а нужно говорить "ПОЕХАЛ"? Человек рассуждал по аналогии. Он написал: "Я поехал в Петербург четыре года назад, там посещал курсы три недели".

После моего исправления - "Ездил в Петербург" - последовал вопрос: "Почему Ездил, а не ПОЕХАЛ?". Про последовательность "Поехал - поступил" я понял. Что, "мы ВСЕГДА используем глаголы несовершенного вида" - это  прочитал в правилах. )) Теперь понятно, что не всегда в данных случаях используют НСВ.

Но как все-таки ответить на эти вопросы? По каким критериям определять, когда используется глаголы СВ и НСВ именно  в этих случаях?    Можно ли сказать, что когда есть 1 глагол в СВ/НСВ, нужно и второй использовать также? ПОЕХАЛ - ПОСТУПИЛ. ЕЗДИЛ - ПОСЕЩАЛ?
"В первом варианте перечисляется последовательность действий, которая заканчивается поступлением на курсы (поехал, поступил). "Глагол "ездить" использовать нельзя, так как он предполагает возвращение обратно". Но человек, закончив курсы в городе Х, через год вернулся обратно домой. Или имеется ввиду, что поехал - это более длительное время, чем ездил/съездил? "Ездил - это значит съездил и вернулся, в то время как он в действительности поступил на курсы. "Но во 2 случае он тоже посещал курсы 3 недели. И сколько времени он пробыл в Петербурге неизвестно.  И я не очень понял, почему "Если во втором варианте использовать глагол «поехал», то последовательность действий будет нарушена: только поехал в город, но не приехал". Может быть, есть какое-то правила, чтобы было легче все это объяснить?

Answer (score 4):

> > Почему нельзя сказать: "Я ездил на год в город Х и поступил на курсы"

Можно.

> > Он написал: "Я поехал в Петербург четыре года назад, там посещал курсы три недели". После моего исправления - "Ездил в Петербург" - последовал вопрос: "Почему Ездил, а не ПОЕХАЛ?"

Действительно, почему? Можно и поехал.

Не придумывайте трудности там, где их нет.